# Is there any way to make a multi-line comment in Python?

Tags: python, comments

I just started Python yesterday, and I was just wondering, is there any way to make a multi-line comment in Python? I only know to do it with a hashtag, but it is quite annoying to constantly use a hashtag over and over again on multiple lines. Thanks!

Comment: The title of the duplicate is almost identical to your title. Did you do a search first?

Comment: No, I only started stack overflow in January and this is my first post, so no.

Comment: With proper editor support, you don't need multiline comments.